# MultiDimensionalarray manipulation in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like below --

[input array](http://pastebin.com/9ruDw3tr)

I want the array to be like ----
[output](http://pastebin.com/EJeMyc82)

How I can loop through this array to get desired output ?
Kindly guide.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know anything about foreach or other kind of loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this --

```
    foreach($new_array as $item) //// for looping outer array
         {
             foreach($item as $n)
                {
                      $newArray[$n[7]] = $n[8]; /// for looping inner array
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you won't put any research effort into the question yourself, I'll just give you the half answer ...

```
foreach($inputArray as $i) {
    $newArray[$i[7]] = $i[8];
}
```

Now you just have to add them into the specific array. Tip: You need another foreach loop.